# File pointers after returning from a forked child process

Tags: c++, c, fork, file-descriptor

Is it normal, for a given file descriptor shared between a forked parent and child process, that the file position in the parent process remains the same after a child process reads from the same file descriptor?

This is happening for me.  Here's the setup:

I am writing a C++ CGI program, so it reads http requests from stdin.  When processing a multipart_form, I process stdin with an intermediary object (Multipart_Pull) that has a getc() method that detects the boundary strings and returns EOF at the end of a each field, so I can pretend a field's contents are a file.  When the field is a file upload, I fork twice in order to pipe the results of Multipart_Pull::getc to the stdin of a child process that runs `ssconvert` to make a CSV file from an Excel file for further processing.  I wrote the child process to leave the file pointer at the position where the parent could pick it up.  The parent process uses wait() to ensure the child processes are done before continuing.

For testing while developing Multipart_Pull, I am faking stdin by opening a disk file that was copied from a real multipart_form request.

When faking stdin, and after the child process returns, the first character read in the parent process is the same first character that the child process read when it started.  That is, the file pointer didn't move in the parent's copy of the file.

I have confirmed that the child process actually reads the data by running gdb and following the appropriate child process by using `set follow-fork-mode child`, and also confirmed the file position of the parent on return by comparing the characters read against the file from which the data is read.

When I am really reading from stdin, I don't expect that this will be a problem because (correct me if I'm wrong here), when you read a character from stdin, it's gone forever.

I realize that there are workarounds to solve this particular problem, the easiest being to just ignore any fields that follow a file upload on a multipart_form, i.e. the parent doesn't try to continue reading after the fork.  However, I hate to cripple the production code or make unnecessary restrictions, and mainly because I really just want to understand what's happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post an MCVE:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it normal, for a given file descriptor shared between a forked parent and child process, that the file position in the parent process remains the same after a child process reads from the same file descriptor?

Since you bring up `fork()`, I presume you are working with a POSIX-compliant system.  Otherwise, the answer is subject to the specific details of your C++ implementation.

In POSIX terminology, file descriptors and streams are both types of "handles" on an underlying "open file description".  There may be multiple distinct handles on the same open file description, potentially held by different processes.  The `fork()` function is one way in which such a situation may arise.

In the event that multiple handles on the same open file description are manipulated, POSIX explicitly declares the results unspecified except under [specific conditions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_05.html#tag_02_05_01).  Your child processes satisfy their part of those requirements by closing their streams, either explicitly or as a consequence of normal process termination.  According to POSIX, however, for the parent's subsequent use of its stream to have specified behavior, it "shall perform an lseek() or fseek() (as appropriate to the type of handle) to an appropriate location."

In other words, the parent process cannot rely on the child processes' manipulation of the file offset to automatically be visible to it, and in fact cannot rely on any particular offset at all after the children manipulate their copies of the stream.

Comment: Thank you an explanation and a source where I can learn more about the issues involved. The specification is still a bit fuzzy to me, however.  The sentence you reference that mentions a need to lseek or fseek refers to a "function that explicitly changed the file offset" as the predicate to the need to perform the seek command.  The document earlier distinguishes between the implicit file offset effect of read and write operations in contrast to the explicit file offset effect of lseek,

Comment: @chuckj, yes, standards can be tricky to interpret.  I take any function that performs a read or write on the stream to have changing the file offset among its explicit effects.  On that basis I assert that the constraint given applies to your parent process.

Comment: @chuckj, as a practical matter, do consider that many streams maintain internal I/O buffers, which will interfere with other handles on the same open file description seeing the same logical file position.  The specs are written more broadly than to accommodate only that case, but if you consider the various implications of buffering -- in each process -- then I think you will appreciate some of the reasons why the specs say what they do.

Comment: I had previously thought that the two handles generated by a fork referred to a single description, so a position change in one process would be visible in both, and that the description resided outside of both processes.  I thought this because it seems that the system somehow keeps a count of how many processes have a handle to the open file, otherwise closing the file in one process would close it in all.  With a reference count outside of the memory spaces of the separate processes, it seemed reasonable to expect a common file position value as well.

Comment: @chuckj, most of what you thought is correct.  If you have an open stream in one process, then forking that process creates a separate stream referring to the same underlying open file description.  The system does keep track of open handles on each open file description, and thereby avoids closing that OFD while any handles on it remain open.  Even if otherwise that would permit a common file position, however, buffering inside streams establishes different views of what the file position actually is.  Stream buffers belong to the process, not the system.