# In C++, calling fork when cin is a bash heredoc causes repeated input fragments

Tags: c++, bash, fork, istream, heredoc

I am implementing a shell-like program in C++. It has a loop that reads from cin, forks, and waits for the child.

This works fine if the input is interactive or if it's piped from another program. However, when the input is a [bash heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), the program rereads parts of the input (sometimes indefinitely).

I understand that the child process inherits the parent's file descriptors, including shared file offset. However, the child in this example does not read anything from cin, so I think it shouldn't touch the offset. I'm kind of stumped about why this is happening.

---

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) { // child
            break; // exit immediately
        }
        else if (pid > 0) { // parent
            waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0);
        }
        else { // error
            perror("fork");
        }

        std::cout << getpid() << ": " << line << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it as follows:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++11
```

Then I run it with:

```
./a.out <<EOF
hello world
goodbye world
EOF
```

Output:

```
7754: hello world
7754: goodbye world
7754: goodbye world
```

If I add a third line `foo bar` to the input command, the program gets stuck in an infinite loop:

```
13080: hello world
13080: goodbye world
13080: foo bar
13080: o world
13080: goodbye world
13080: foo bar
13080: o world
[...]
```

---

Versions:

- Linux kernel: 4.4.0-51-generic
- Ubuntu: 16.04.1 LTS (xenial)
- bash: GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- gcc: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: What happens if you do `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` at the beginning and explicitly flush after your write to stdout? (e.g. change `'\n'` to `std::endl`)

Comment: By stracing the child process, I can see exactly what's going on. The child process lseeks backwards on file descriptor 0 before exiting, which affects the parent process. Unfortunately, I don't know why the C library is doing that, so I'm not going to post the details as an answer. This also happens with an explicit `exit(0);` but not `_exit(0);`.

Comment: the answer here might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899548/file-pointers-after-returning-from-a-forked-child-process

Comment: @Hurkyl yes, that fixes it! I guess because C library is seeking stdout (per @SamVarshavchik), turning off synchronization changes the child process's effect.

Comment: @Erix Thanks, that's really helpful. So maybe the "right" way to fix this is calling `fclose(stdin)` etc at the beginning of the child, to prevent exit from seeking in the first place.

Comment: @Kevin: Interesting! I wonder if the problem, then, is in the C library, or the interaction between the C and C++ libraries? What if you close `cin` after forking (I don't remember if you can do that; if not, you could set its badbit or something)?  What if you rewrite the program to use the C io routines?

Comment: ... also, it's probably worth testing with a larger heredoc size; enough to overflow up a whole `cin` buffer, maybe twice.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this, but you absolutely should be `_exit`'ing or `quick_exit`'ting  from the forked child if the child doesn't `exec`. The parent builds up `cout` buffer state and the children inherit it. If the children exit regularly, they will attempt to flush their copy of the `cout` buffer which should be getting flushed in the parent. If this happens, you will get duplicates in your output.

Comment: @PSkocik you just should flush buffers before a `fork` if this is a concern.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik AFAIU failure to rewind stdin was considered a glibc bug back when.

Comment: @Hurkyl the behavior persists when I add `std::cin.setstate(std::ios::failbit);` to the beginning of the child. It also happens when I rewrite the program to use getline and printf (compiled with both c++11 and c11). And the problem goes away when I make the child sleep instead of calling exit. So it seems like exit is the culprit here.

Comment: don't use nullptr for C lib. nullptr is C++, use NULL when you use C function.

Comment: @KevinChen this has nothing to do with C++ streams. You need to call `close(0)` before exiting.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this problem, not only using the heredoc but also using a standard file redirection.

Here is the test script that I used. In both the first and second cases, I got a duplication of the  second line of input.

```
./a.out < Input.txt
echo

cat Input.txt | ./a.out
echo

./a.out <<EOF
hello world
goodbye world
EOF
```

Closing the `stdin` before exiting in the child seems to eliminate both of the problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) { // child
            close(STDIN_FILENO);
            break; // exit after first closing stdin
        }
        else if (pid > 0) { // parent
            waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0);
        }
        else { // error
            perror("fork");
        }

        std::cout << getpid() << ": " << line << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```